# Windows 11 forgets RADIUS WIFI Credentials

Tags: windows, authentication, wireless-networking, radius

We have a number of Windows 11 notebooks in our family. All updated to the latest version of WinPro. And all suffer the same problem: every once in a while, these devices forget the RADIUS credentials for the WiFi. The RADIUS service is hosted by a dedicated provider.
Sometimes a device connects to the WiFi over weeks, sometimes it forgets the credentials twice a day. What's even more annoying is that a reboot does not help. Once forgotten, the user has to reenter the username & password.

This problem is isolated to Windows (10 & 11). Other devices (e.g. Android, iPhone, Mac, Linux etc.) have no problems reconnecting.

My network:

- UniFi UDM Pro with 2 AP
- RADIUS service is hosted externally.

Any idea how to get Windows NOT forgetting the credentials or how to work around this issue?

Comment: Are you sure it is not the RADIUS server having intermittent issues where it starts rejecting the credentials as "invalid"? Some clients deliberately forget stored credentials in such cases instead of retrying forever.

Comment: Based on the log files I have available, I don't have any failed log in attempts from these devices.
The fact that only Windows devices are affected is curious to me.